# How to interpret and react to Shorewall log?

Tags: debian, firewall

I see the following pattern in every 2-3 sec, for several minutes in syslog:

```
Shorewall:net2fw:DROP:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:gg:hh:ii:jj:kk:ll:mm:nn SRC=12.34.56.78 DST=98.76.54.32 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=41 ID=12746 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41611 DPT=22 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

where values at ID and SPT are different in each line.The server is Debian 6.0, with shorewall and fail2ban.

How can I narrow down what is going on and use fail2ban and shorewall to better block this?

Comment: Looks like tcpdump output, but what the reason of this message i don't know.

Comment: That's a connection attempt to port 22 (`DPT=` destination port, `SYN` = connection establishment attempt) on your machine (SSH).

Answer (score 1):

My solution ended up at this Fail2ban filter:

```
failregex = DROP:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=[a-zA-F0-9:]+ SRC=<HOST> DST=([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4} LEN=
            DROP:IN=eth0 OUT=vmbr0 SRC=<HOST> DST=([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4} LEN=
```

added to `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd-ddos.conf`

It bans these requests on ssh port.